# Is there a way to use Next.js API Routes to Authenticate Django Rest Framework backend?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, next.js

I'm using DRF as a backend to Next.js frontend. I followed [this very fine tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnGR6W3w0l8&t=3838s) to set up authentication, but I read I should use Next.js API Routes as proxy to the DRF API Routes and I can do that on any route other than the authentication one because I must send the `X-CSRFToken` and `credentials: "include"` in the request headers. Currently I'm getting the CSRF Token on page load with `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(()=> {

    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api-auth/csrf",{
      credentials: "include"
    })
    .then( res => setCsrf(res.headers.get("X-CSRFToken")))
    .catch( err => console.error(err))

  },[])
```

Im using a direct route to DRF API `"http://localhost:8000/api-auth/csrf"` instead of a Next.js API like `"/api-auth/csrf"`. The same happens with the `handleLogin` function:

```js
const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api-auth/login/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrf
      },
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(formValues),
    })
    .then(() => Router.push("/profile"))
  };
```

It is working like this, but I can't set credentials using Next.js API Routes. Even using the same pattern it doesn't work. I think I'm missing some fundamental concept here and I looked it up but couldn't find. If anyone can help I'd appreciate :)